# Software installation

Tags: software-installation, authentication

Installing new software requires a password in my ubuntu.
How do I switch this option off?
(I know my password, I just want to speed up the process)

Thnx in advance!

Comment: linux dont let you do that, they locked that just for saying' linux is more secure than any  os', so if you dont like it, delete ubuntu and go back to windows

Comment: You could make your default user root, but that's really not secure at all.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful when playing with sudo setup as you may end up without sudo access if something goes wrong. Using `sudo visudo` (it opens file in a editor and validates before overwriting the original file) add following to your sudoers file (replacing 'youruser' with your actual username):

```
youruser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

A lot more about `sudoers` file is available in system manual (`man sudoers`) or Ubuntu's wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thnx!